# My custom Adapter displays things sometimes wrong

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, adapter, baseadapter

I did write a custom Adapter for my Android Application (Xamarin, c#) to display "Mods", with some values like name, game etc. Here you can see it:

```
public class modAdapter : BaseAdapter<Mod>
{
    List<Mod> items;
    Activity context;

    public modAdapter(Activity context, List<Mod> items)
   : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Mod this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
            row = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.modRow, null, false);

        row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = items[position].name;
        row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2).Text = items[position].game;

        if (items[position].favorited)
            row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.favIcon).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        return row;
    }
}
```

I have added an icon into the rows for the ListView which gets visible if the user has marked the mod as a favorite. The items list is correct, I debugged and checked, I have only one favorite.

But strangely sometimes other mods get marked as a favorite, even though they aren't marked in the list. I think this happens when you scroll and the missing rows get viewed. I debugged and looked when the line where the icon gets visible is called, and it gets only called when the right mod is loaded. Still one other (the last in the list) gets the icon.

I am pretty new to Android Development and really hope you understand my problem and have some ideas to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list elements are being recycled, so once a view is used for a "favorite" it sets the icon visible. When that element goes off screen, that element's layout is reused on another element. The icon is still visible from the

```
row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.favIcon).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

line. So add an else block and set the visibility back to hidden or gone.

As a side note, you can look into `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder` for a better understanding of recycling and to some possible improvements to your code.